# How do I set File Manager default view in 16.04

Tags: filemanager

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. This is probably a simple question, but for some reason, I can't figure out how to change the default view in File Manager to list. I tried one of the other posts, "File manager doesn't remember list preferences," but I didn't see any way to get into Preferences when I'm in File Manager. Can someone fill me in on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Edit > Preferences.

Comment: Very simple. Thank you. I forgot the menu is hidden until the cursor hits it.

Answer (score 0):

Move the cursor to the top edge of your screen to enable the menu and click on *Edit* > *Preferences* to open the *Files Preferences* dialog:

[image: Edit > Preferences]

Set *List View* as the new default for new folders:

[image: Selecting default view]